# Update specific column in all tables base on specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to update all table based on my value. This is a script Task in my SSIS package.

But I get the error:

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Code looks like this:

```
DECLARE @Column_name varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @Column_Datatype varchar(max)

SET @COLUMN_NAME='site_id'
SET @COLUMN_DATATYPE='varchar(10)'

------------------------------------------------Code---------------------------------------------------
GO
--Declare Variables
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TableSchema VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME_UPDATE VARCHAR(50)
SET @COLUMN_NAME_UPDATE = ?
SET @COLUMN_NAME='site_id' 
DECLARE @COLUMN_DATATYPE VARCHAR(50)
SET @COLUMN_DATATYPE='varchar(max)' 

--Declare Cursor
DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
  SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,
         TABLE_NAME
  FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
--OPEN CURSOR
OPEN CUR
--Fetch First Row
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @TableSchema,@TableName
--Loop
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
  SET @SQL= ( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
       WHERE TABLE_NAME=@TableName AND COLUMN_NAME=@COLUMN_NAME 
and Table_Schema=@TableSchema)
  BEGIN
    SET @SQL='UPDATE '+ @TableSchema+'.'+ '[' + @TableName + ']' + ' SET '+@COLUMN_NAME + '='
                         + '''' + @COLUMN_NAME_UPDATE + '''' + 'WHERE site_id IS NULL '
    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC ( @SQL)
  END
 
      FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @TableSchema,@TableName
  END
--Close and Deallocate Cursor
CLOSE CUR
DEALLOCATE CUR
```

I use a variable like input.

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Aside... object and data type names are of the `SYSNAME` type, which is a synonym for `NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL`. Not only could you be truncating object names with your `varchar(50)` and `varchar(100)` variables - you could be converting any present Unicode characters to `?` and no longer matching the original names.

Comment: Delete the first 5 lines until the `Go` command. The problem will be fixed

Comment: Should be `'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' SET '+ QUOTENAME(@COLUMN_NAME) + ' = ' + QUOTENAME(@COLUMN_NAME_UPDATE, '''') + ' WHERE site_id IS NULL;'`